# remove duplicate elements inside python list

Tags: python

I have lists containing sequence of numbers like below:

```
list_1 = [4.5 ,4.5 ,4, 4 ,4, 5, 5, 5]
list_2 = [6.5 ,7 ,7 ,8 ,8]
list_3 = [14.5 ,15 ,15 , 15.5]
```

I want to remove duplicates from those list in a way that if list contain repetition keep only one occurrence, and preserve the order:

```
list_1 = [4.5 ,4, 5]
list_2 = [6.5 ,7 ,8]
list_3 = [14.5 ,15 , 15.5]
```

Comment: Better yet, if you don't care about order just use a `set()`. Please remember to _search_ before asking a new question. This has been asked many times before. See [ask].

Comment: I want to preserve the order

Comment: Then please take a look at the first duplicate that I proposed. And please also read my comment about searching.

Comment: thanks, list(dict.fromkeys(list_with_duplicates)) work very well

Answer (score 3):

If order does not matter, cast them to a set.

```
list_1 = [4.5 ,4.5 ,4, 4 ,4, 5, 5, 5]
list_2 = [6.5 ,7 ,7 ,8 ,8]
list_3 = [14.5 ,15 ,15 , 15.5]

list_1 = list(set(list_1))
list_2 = list(set(list_2))
list_3 = list(set(list_3))
```

If order does matter, use a de-duplication function.

```
def dedupe(lst):
    items = []
    for item in lst:
        if item not in items:
            items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: no, I need to preserve the order